# Scarce / non-renewable items

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm trying not to be too vague here, as I suspect a complete answer would require a massive Wiki/DB, but which items are "renewable" vs "scarce" ?

Obviously "boss" parts like Queen Endraga Pheremones or Kayran bits are unique, but:

If I'm looking for silver ore, will there always be some around?
Most crafting components can themselves be crafted, but are the raw materials always plentiful, or is there a limited amount of iron ore in each town?

What about monsters, am I going to end up wishing I'd saved more Nekker parts because there are finite Nekkers spawned in the game?
Is there a danger of "missing out" on various components, or can I theoretically just grind local creatures to produce whatever I need (assuming sufficient money for the purchasing and crafting labor)?

Comment: interesting question, especially about the ones like the Nekker.

Comment: Silver and Iron ore can be bought from smiths. Like all shop inventories, they have a chance to restock after 24 in-game hours. Monster spawns are not finite either - you can run into Nekkers and Endrega even after completing both contracts. As to whether or not you can find Endrega or Neckers beyond act 1, I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inventory of merchants does respawn after a while, you have to meditate for about 24-48 hours and there should be a new selection of stuff to buy. I used that to get enough iron and silver ore for some swords, as the shop did not sell enough of the ore at once to craft the new sword.

Plants also do respawn after a short while, those you also can farm indefinitely. I'm not sure if you can get every single alchemy ingredient everywhere just from plants and respawning monsters, but there is usually an alchemy shop in every area so you should be able to buy anything you're missing. Except for certain quests, you only need the 9 base alchemy types, you don't need any specific ingredients, just something that e.g. contains Quebrith.

So, as long as you have enough money and the merchants generally stock the items you need, you shouldn't run out of crafting ingredients.

Comment: I'll add to that, the rare, quest alchemical items appear interchangeable too. The Kayran Tissue and the Queen Endrega Pheromones can both be substitution for Ostmurk in the mongoose potion.

Comment: Yes, for alchemy all that matters is which alchemy component it contains (vermillion, ether, etc).  Crafting items is pickier, you can't make Kayran armor with Queen Endrega phermones.